# adb: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by adb)

Tags: linux, centos

I am getting below error while running adb in linux(centos).

$ adb

adb: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by adb)

adb: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by adb)

adb: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by adb)

Any help will be appropriated!

Regards,

Esanya

Comment: See what version you are running with `ldd --version`. Afterwards you can always use yum to install libc6. Command should be `yum install libc6`

Comment: ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.23
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

Comment: sudo yum install libc6
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.linuxfix.com
 * epel: mirror.layeronline.com
 * extras: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
 * updates: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
No package libc6 available.
Error: Nothing to do